# Moq test if an attribute was changed in a method that returns void

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-4, moq

I'd like to know if its possible to test, using Moq, if some attribute in an object was changed by some method, that method must be void.

i want to check if the attribute "FlgActive" of product was changed from true to false.

the delete method is void, and it just change that flag to false.

if its possible, what should i add to my setup to check that ?

Example:

TEST

```
[TestMethod]
    public void DeletedProductFlagShouldBeFalse() //RN03
    {
        var product = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "aaaaaa", Code = "aaaaaa", FlgActive = true };
        var so = new ServiceOrder() {  };

        var mockProductRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        mockProductRepository.Setup(p => p.Delete(product));

        var mockServiceOrderRepository = new Mock<IServiceOrderRepository>();
        mockServiceOrderRepository.Setup(o => o.GetProductById(product.Id)).Returns(new List<ServiceOrder> { so });

        var service = new ProductService(mockProductRepository.Object, mockServiceOrderRepository.Object);

        service.Delete(product);

        mockProductRepository.Verify(c => c.Delete(It.IsAny<Product>()), Times.Once());
        mockProductRepository.Verify((s => s.Commit()), Times.Once());

        Assert.IsFalse(product.FlgActive);
    }
```

SERVICE

```
public void Delete(Product product)
    {
        Validate(product);
        repo.Delete(product);
        repo.Commit();
    }
```

REPOSITORY

```
public void Delete(Product product)
    {
        try
        {
            product.FlgActive = false;
            Update(product);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this assert already doing that `Assert.IsFalse(product.FlgActive);`?

Comment: It is not your service duty to check if the product has its flag set to false. Your service job is to check that the repo has been called correctly. The unit test of your repository should check if the flag is set correctly.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault can you, please, explain to me how to do that using moq ?

Comment: @Gouki0 Your issue is not really related to Moq itself, but more what to test. I've added an answer which should be more detailed. A mock is used to isolate your class from the outside world, you can't expect it to have logic (like setting your flag to false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your service which is setting the flag to false, so you should not test that behavior from your service. The job of this unit is to validate the product, then delegate the deletion to the repository.

So you can remove that part from your test and rename it:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeletionShouldBeSentToRepository() //RN03
{
    var product = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "aaaaaa", Code = "aaaaaa", FlgActive = true };
    var so = new ServiceOrder() {  };

    var mockProductRepository = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mockProductRepository.Setup(p => p.Delete(product));

    var mockServiceOrderRepository = new Mock<IServiceOrderRepository>();
    mockServiceOrderRepository.Setup(o => o.GetProductById(product.Id)).Returns(new List<ServiceOrder> { so });

    var service = new ProductService(mockProductRepository.Object, mockServiceOrderRepository.Object);

    service.Delete(product);

    mockProductRepository.Verify(c => c.Delete(product), Times.Once());
    mockProductRepository.Verify((s => s.Commit()), Times.Once());
}
```

***NOTE***: I's good to verify we're sending the good product to the repo. I've replaced your `It.IsAny` with the product you created previously.

Now that we covered the duties of your service, we can test the deletion behavior into the repo itself, which should look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeletedProductFlagShouldBeFalse() //RN03
{
    var product = new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "aaaaaa", Code = "aaaaaa", FlgActive = true };

    IProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();

    repository.Delete(product);

    Assert.IsFalse(product.FlgActive);
}
```

When you're doing unit tests, it's important to test only the behavior of the current class, not the side effects.

Comment: So, its impossible to test if some attribute was changed by mocking the repository. What i was really trying to achieve was to assert a business logic = "Delete should change product flag to false". Anyway, thanks man, it was very helpful.

Comment: @Gouki0 Well it's possible, if you test the correct class. You can test your business logic by testing the repository itself, like the last example. If you want to test the business logic between multiple classes (i.e. an integration test), use real classes instead of mocks. A Mock removes all the logic inside the methods so you can fake the outputs.